# Create Play Apllication with Typesafe Activator

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I need to develop an application with help of the Play Framework. I used to develop some apps with it previously, however currently we are supposed to create play applications with the Typesafe Activator.

What I need to know is can someone provide a website, link or a short answer which explains in more details how a new application is created with Typesafe Activator explaining how it works in more detail.

Where is the `PLAY_HOME` directory is actually located?

What would happen to our project if a new update is needed?

Is it going to effect the project or not?

Answer (score 3):

Typesafe Activator,  behind the scenes is just sbt. When you create a new application either with the UI or `activator new` sbt will download all dependencies any part of the play API will be in the local repository(typically `activator\repository`). Also, your project structure is determined by the [template](http://typesafe.com/activator/templates/) you choose Most everything, including runs, are managed by the sbt. If you want to go into detail, I suggest you look at the sbt docs at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/
. In order to change any build configuration you will need to modify your sbt file.

If by updates you mean the updates to the Scala version or play version. You may have to go into the activator file and update you dependency versions / Scala version. IF you mean updates to the activator, it will update itself when t detects a new version.